# How To Intent Image Button In Navigation Drawer Header

Tags: android, android-intent, imagebutton

I dont know how to start a intent `ImageButton` on `nav_header_main`. I must add new java class or I just use the MainActivity.java
Please help me. Thank you

[image: example on the image]

Comment: did u try something? code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is xml code of nav_header_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can access this button from MainActivity onCreate() after the NavigationView is initialized.

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
       //DO YOUR CODE
    }
 });
```

Comment: I put that code in the bottom of 

`NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`

But when I run,it is force close

Answer (score 1):

I test `navigationView.findViewById` with auto generate sample by Android stduio, and not work correctly.

Other solution

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
       //DO YOUR CODE
    }
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

Get the id of your image button.

```
 ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view){
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourClass.class);
 startActivity(intent,0);
 }
 });
```